# How to style auto-generated elements in xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm using this extension [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42227/Automatic-WPF-Toolkit-DataGrid-Filtering) toolkit, it automatically adds a `TextBox` to the top of each DataGrid column for filtering from the following code.

```
<DataGrid ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource {ComponentResourceKey 
       TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type filter:DataGridHeaderFilterControl}, 
       ResourceId=DataGridHeaderFilterControlStyle}}" >
```

However, the added column header and the textboxes have a different style from what I want.

So I can do this to style the column header, but it won't change the textboxes.

```
<Style x:Key="FilterHeader"
        BasedOn="{StaticResource {ComponentResourceKey TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type filter:DataGridHeaderFilterControl},
                                                        ResourceId=DataGridHeaderFilterControlStyle}}"
        TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">

    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue" />

</Style>

...

<DataGrid ColumnHeaderStyle="{DynamicResource FilterHeader}">
```

I tried putting this in`Window.Resources` to see if it had an effect on the textboxes. It changed my other textboxes it doesn't have any effect on the textboxes created by the extension.

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue" />
</Style>
```

But no dice. The only thing I've found that works is this:

```
    public void DataGrid_OnLoad(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        IEnumerable<System.Windows.Controls.TextBox> collection =
            FindVisualChildren<System.Windows.Controls.TextBox>(TitleBar);

        foreach (System.Windows.Controls.TextBox tb in collection)
        {
            tb.Foreground = Brushes.Blue;
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> FindVisualChildren<T>(DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        if (depObj != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
            {
                DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);
                if (child != null && child is T)
                {
                    yield return (T)child;
                }

                foreach (T childOfChild in FindVisualChildren<T>(child))
                {
                    yield return childOfChild;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But that seems like a garbage way of doing it. How can I do this purely in xaml or at least more cleanly in C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking through the source code, i noticed that the `TextBox` isn't really a textbox but a subclass of Textbox. `DelayTextBox`

So you could just modify your style to target that instead.

```
<Style TargetType="DelayTextBox">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue" />
</Style>
```

I haven't tried it but it should work.

**Update**

Finally found the issue. The styles should be defined within a style of their parent.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type filter:DataGridColumnFilter}">
    <Style.Resources>

        <Style TargetType="{x:Type support:DelayTextBox}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue" />
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
        </Style>

        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue" />
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

I've added the comboxbox since i assume you'd want that too. you can take out the setter for bold as needed .. was using it to test.

Comment: I had to change it to `<Style TargetType="support:DelayTextBox">` for it to recognize the class, but unfortunately it didn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: Stackoverflow amazes once again. This has been bugging me for ages. Thanks scartag.